# Terms aggregation not returning other buckets

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm not able to get other buckets with terms aggregation when combining a filter aggregation. Anyway to do this in elasticsearch?

Mapping: customer with nested address. address with nested properties.

I've tried the following,

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "address": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "address"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "shipping_to_address": {
          "aggs": {
            "city": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "address.city.name.keyword",
                "size": 10,
                "missing": "others"
              }
            }
          },
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "nested": {
                    "path": "address.properties",
                    "query": {
                      "bool": {
                        "filter": [
                          {
                            "term": {
                              "address.properties.type": "shipping_to"
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The above only returns the buckets matching the filter.

```
{
  "hits": {
    "total": 3,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "address": {
      "doc_count": 3,
      "shipping_to_address": {
        "doc_count": 1,
        "city": {
          "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
          "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
          "buckets": [
            {
              "key": "new york",
              "doc_count": 1
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to see the other buckets as below:

```
          "buckets": [
            {
              "key": "new york",
              "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
              "key": "others",
              "doc_count": 2
            }      
          ]
```

Comment: please add mapping

Comment: Mapping: {"mappings":{"doc":{"properties":{"address":{"type":"nested","dynamic":"false","properties":{"city":{"properties":{"name":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword"}}}}},"country":{"properties":{"name":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword"}}}}},"county":{"properties":{"name":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword"}}}}},"properties":{"type":"nested","properties":{"isPrimary":{"type":"keyword"},"type":{"type":"keyword"}}},"province":{"properties":{"name":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword"}}}}}}}}}}}

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "min_doc_count":0 to terms aggregation, it will return empty buckets.
[Link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_minimum_document_count_4) for reference

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "address": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "address"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "shipping_to_address": {
          "aggs": {
            "city": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "address.city.name.keyword",
                "size": 10,
                "min_doc_count":0,
                "missing": "others"
              }
            }
          },
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "nested": {
                    "path": "address.properties",
                    "query": {
                      "bool": {
                        "filter": [
                          {
                            "term": {
                              "address.properties.type": "shipping_to"
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found out 'missing' is for the document that does not have value, not for the rest of the document that does not match a filter.

Comment: yes, missing is a filler where value is not present.